# What's the fastest way to add two arrays of integers in clojure?

Tags: performance, clojure

This seems slow:

```
(time (doall (map + (range 1000000) (range 1000000))))
"Elapsed time: 13951.664454 msecs"
```

How to do it faster?

Comment: see also `amap` clojuredoc [here](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/amap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, range does not make an array, it makes a lazy-seq.

The fastest way to add two collections of numbers is probably going to involve having them in arrays first, and doing an iterative loop instead of a map.

```
user> (time (let [a (int-array (range 1000000))
                  b (int-array (range 1000000))]
              (dotimes [i 1000000]
              (aset a i (+ (aget b i) (aget a i))))
              a))
"Elapsed time: 771.100395 msecs"
#<int[] [I@4233eba0>
user>
```

Note this still has the overhead of creating and realizing the lazy seqs from the two range calls, in actual performance you would likely already have that data constructed before getting to the summation step.

Unless this is a performance bottleneck in your code, doing things this way would imply you shouldn't be using clojure in the first place. The advantage of using clojure is you get high level immutable data structures, which lead to referentially transparent and parallelizable code. Once you drop down to raw jvm types like arrays, you lose these advantages (in exchange for better performance).

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in Prismatic's ["open-source array processing library HipHip, which combines Clojure's expressiveness with the fastest math Java has to offer"](http://blog.getprismatic.com/blog/2013/7/10/introducing-hiphip-array-fast-and-flexible-numerical-computation-in-clojure).

I just had a quick go with it and it does seem to offer a nice compromise between expressiveness and performance:

Note: I'm using [Criterium](https://github.com/hugoduncan/criterium) to benchmark this as it reduces some of the problems with benchmarking on the JVM.

```
 (require '[criterium.core :refer [quick-bench]])

 (quick-bench (doall (map + (range 1000000) (range 1000000))))
 ;=> "Execution time mean : 791.955406 ms"

 (require '[hiphip.int :as h])
 (quick-bench (h/amap [x (h/amake [i 1000000] i)
                       y (h/amake [i 1000000] i)]
                 (+ x y)))
 ;=> "Execution time mean : 20.540645 ms"
```